# What is the better way to parse args like arg="value" in haskell?

Tags: haskell

I have to receive some arguments of a program in the wey `argx=valueX argy=valueY` or `argx="valueX" argy="valueY"`, where the args are `String`s, and having a default value if nothing is passed, so I made this function for calling it from `main`:

```hs
import Data.List.Extra ( stripPrefix, firstJust )

{- obtainArg:
    If in args there is a string like keyWord=something or keyWord="something"
    returns something, if not it return defaultValue
-}
obtainArg :: String -> String -> [String] -> String
obtainArg defaultValue keyWord args = 
    case firstJust (stripPrefix $ keyWord ++ "=") args of
        Nothing -> defaultValue
        Just xs ->
            case readsPrec 11 xs of
                [] -> xs
                ((x,_):_) -> x
```

But I was wondering if there is not a better way of doing that. Somebody has a suggestion about how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's not really possible to make an unopinionated and future-proof library recommendation (and so this question is a bit off-topic for this forum), I think it is possible to make some unopinionated search term recommendations. If you haven't already, the right search term is "parsing". The popular approaches at the moment break down into two categories, "parser generators" and "parser combinators". At the moment, it is generally the case that combinators have less programmer overhead, while generators have less program runtime overhead.

If these strings are coming in as arguments to your program (as opposed to being read from a file or fed via `stdin`), you may also want to look specifically at "command line option parsers". If they are coming from a URL, then "URL parsers" is a more appropriate search.